# If HiiT only, How many times a week?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, hiit

I don't have much time to work out for long time session, so I'm just training according to HiiT protocol four times a week, it takes me up to 15mins per session.

If it is Ok for the body to take HiiT as the only training routine without weightlifting or running, how many time a week should I workout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is ok.

According to some research, e.g. [NY Times- 4 minute workout](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/19/the-4-minute-workout/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=1&) once  a week of 4 minutes high intensity training is enough to improve. Similar as [Mosley](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2538858/Can-exercising-just-60-seconds-week-transform-health-The-BBCs-Dr-Michael-Mosley-says-fast-exercise-powerful-experts-thought.html) of BBC recommends.

My own experience is that if you fill the high intensity training sessions with full body exercises that engage all of your posterior chain, (e.g. [burpees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_Dq_NCzj8M) or [kettlebell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_XjJjLc7NE) swings) you will also improve/sustain your strength.

This way the other workouts can be focused on improving specific skills, e.g. swimming, running, or team sports such as football, basketball, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have completed and trained a number of people in several High-intensity interval training (HIIT) programs.

Depending on what you are training for or what your goals are only training using HIIT programs may meet your needs.  The programs I have used, and my clients use, we train 6 days a week about 30 minutes a session.  A sound protocol should include body weight exercises that work a range of muscles, and provides some variation across each day within the program to keep your mind and body interested and always working new muscles / muscle groups.

Just because you are not weightlifting or running does not mean you cannot incorporate strength training type exercises within your routine ( think push-ups, pull-ups, planks, plank-walks etc.. )

HIIT programs are an excellent way to get a great full body workout.  15 minute sessions is far better then nothing, I personally would shoot for a bit longer but it sounds like you are doing great.

Keep up the great work!

Comment: my first goal is burning fat, so the question how often should I train a week ? only with HiiT

Comment: Burning fat and losing weight is about calories in and calories out, the real secret to this is what's in your diet, and by diet and simply mean what you eat, and how much you eat (portion size).  Exercise undoubtedly helps but abs are made in the kitchen.